# Query of mongoose mode.find near maxdistance not return correct results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to perform geo search for coordinates and my code is in below:

```
location:{type:[Number],index: '2d'},

Shop.find({location:{$near:loc,$maxDistance: 5}}).limit(50).exec(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      callback(doc);
    });
```

I set the maxDistance: 5 which should return me the point that within 5 km. But the actual results returned always contain points that distance is more than 5km(and even have point with distance of 500km more be returned).

what should i do?

the full code:

```
module.exports = function( mongoose) {
  var ShopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    shopName:     { type: String, unique: true },
    address:     { type: String},
    location:{type:[Number],index: '2d'},
    shopPicUrl:      {type: String},
    shopPicTrueUrl:{type: String},
    mark:  { type: String},
    open:{type:Boolean},
    shopType:{type:String},
    dish:   {type: [{
      dishName: { type: String},
      tags: { type: Array},
      price: { type: Number},
      intro: { type: String},
      dishPic:{ type: String},
      index:{type:Number}
    }]}

  });

  var Shop = mongoose.model('Shop', ShopSchema);

  var createShop = function(shopName, address,location, shopPicUrl, open,shopType,res, callback) {
    var shopInstance = new Shop({
      shopName: shopName,
      address: address,
      location: location,
      shopPicUrl: shopPicUrl,
      open:open,
      shopType:shopType
      //shopPicTrueUrl:shopPicTrueUrl
    });
    shopInstance.save(function(err){
      callback(err);
    });
  };
  return {
    createShop: createShop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> var calculatedMaxDistance = (5) / 6371; 
> /EARTHRADIUSIN KM
>
>
>  Shop.find(
>              {
>                 'geo': {
>                           $near: [lat,long],
>                           $maxDistance: calculatedMaxDistance
>
>                         }
>               }
>       )
> ```

Refer this for radian calculation https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/

Comment: i tried this and the calculatedMaxDistance will be too small and nothing returned. I guess $maxDistance: 5 is exactly mean 5km and I get the result within 5km. But also get point 50km

Comment: (5/120) / 6371; lets try this.

Comment: Can you paste your shop schema here?

Comment: Add this in your schema   "geo": [
    lat,
  long
  ],

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112657/discussion-between-vikram-pote-and-yan-li).